# How to Remove the Lag after taking a picture in android?

Tags: android, optimization, android-camera-intent

I am using the following code for saving a pictures from the camera intent. But when I am interacting with the application their seams to be an optimization problem after clicking OK to accept the picture where it takes like 5 seconds for pictures as big as 3.8Mb.

Saving image from camera to directory:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File outputFile = null;
        try {
            outputFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.example.mohammad.fileprovider",
                outputFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_CODE);
    }
```

The Create Image Function Code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("CloudApp",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("lastImagePath",mCurrentPhotoPath);
    editor.apply();
    return outputFile;
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? How to remove the lag in getting back the result from Camera intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another Thread or AsyncTask to do image saving background with small delay without interrupting user experience. I use AsyncTask to save images even with 4k resolution about 7mb. It takes a while to complete but you don't stop UI and camera thread.

Comment: Does that mean i should use another way to save the image since i don't know were to add the async task here?

Comment: You can manually save image using Camera1 or Camera2, but it would require a bit work, that's where background thread is used. I use Camera1 api,  i save image from data taken from onPictureTaken method of Camera1 api with AsyncTask. I get byte array data and compress it to JPEG or PNG. I don't think it's possible to use a thread with Intent starting Camera.

Comment: Thanks i just figured that i had some stuff i am doing on activity result that i had to add to and asynctask.